# change file name of uploaded file django

Tags: python, django

this is what I am trying to do. I created a method that will upload a file however, I would like to change its file name. I was able to change the filename but I also lost the extension.

this is how my codes look:

```
def upload_delivery_to_media(self,deliveryId, deliveryFile):

    with open('/app/media/TaskDelivery/'+str(delivery), 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in deliveryFile.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

    return "Done uploading"
```

but the file looks like `324329432840932` only when I am expecting something like `324329432840932.jpg`

Comment: `str(delivery)` should be `str(deliveryId)`, right? And you can append a `.jpg` to filename.

Comment: well I also did it but not all the files are .jpg only. some of the them are .gif, .pdf etc

Comment: You can split original filename at `.`  and store extension.  And then append it to your new filename.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I wanted to do.... Thanks... I will search about it

Comment: You can do `extn=filename.split('.')[1]`. And then `newname + '.' + extn`.

Comment: Thank you guys.... It works now

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [splitext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) instead of method `split()`:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

def upload_delivery_to_media(self, delivery_id, delivery_file):
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(delivery_file.name)
    with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'TaskDelivery', '{}{}'.format(delivery_id, ext)), 'wb') as destination:
        for chunk in delivery_file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```